# Why isn't the element display property being redefined?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, display

The problem is that div element with class *layer* is being added to the DOM, but not being displayed, regardless, I've set display property to `flex` to class *layer*

```js
    $("#elem").click(function(e) {
            if (e.target.classList.contains("myClass")) {
                $("*").hide();
                $("body").prepend(`<div class="layer">Hey!</div>`);
            }
  });
```

```css
.layer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: rgb(55, 55, 55);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elem" class="myClass">click me</div>
```

Comment: #elem does not have the class `myClass`

Comment: @ControlAltDel oh yes, it's just how it is in the example shown here. I'll fix that

Comment: Does the div with the class "layer" show if you don't do $("*").hide()?

Comment: Without a working example or a code snippet, it's hard to see where the issue is, maybe give some size and background colors to your elements or use dev tools' inspect element to see why its not visible.

Comment: @ControlAltDel it does

Comment: @Rod911 honestly, I don't know how to make this a work snippet in the SO. I'd reallyappreciate, if you make a edit, and teach me how to do that.

Comment: @Rod911 I've used the tools, but the .layer doesn't display on the screen. Also in my real project the background color and size for .layer are set, and without $(".").hide() everything works just fine. So I presume, the problem is that display: none is not being redefined to display: flex for some reason. (In my project I've added !important to display property, and I'll do that here too in just a sec)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is

```
$("*").hide();
```

If you change this to

```
$("body *").hide();
```

or

```
$("#elem").hide();
```

It should fix your problem

Comment: Now I have another problem: I'm trying to handle click on the .layer element, but click handling event isn't invoked. I do the following: $(".layer").click(function() {console.log("You clicked it!")});  Click handling on the #elem in this script works, but click handling on the .layer doesn't for some mysterious reason. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

You are using `*` as a selector.

> - selector selects all elements in the document, including html, head and body

## Solution

Replace `$("*").hide()` with `$("#elem").hide()`